# Not understanding .net core [FromQuery] or not implementing route matching correctly

Tags: .net-core, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the following request:

```
 https://localhost:44341/odata/Events/?StartDate=2019-05-26T04:00:00.000Z&EndDate=2019-07-07T04:00:00.000Z
```

In the controller I have the following:

```
 [EnableQuery]
    public IActionResult Get([FromQuery]string StartDate, [FromQuery]string EndDate)
    {
        DateTime sDate = Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate);
        DateTime eDate = Convert.ToDateTime(EndDate);
        return Ok(_dbContext.Events.Select(c => c.StartTime >= sDate && c.EndTime <= eDate));
    }


    [EnableQuery]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(_dbContext.Events);
    }
```

I would expect the request to use the first Get with the start and end params. However, it always uses the default. I am not sure what I have done wrong.

Any enlightenment would be appreciated.

Thanks

Here is some output from debug:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:44341/odata/Events/?StartDate=2019-05-26T04:00:00.000Z&EndDate=2019-07-07T04:00:00.000Z
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService:Information: CORS policy execution successful.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Route matched with {action = "Get", controller = "Events"}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult Get() on controller DevOdata.Controllers.EventsController (DevOdata).
```

Comment: Why do you define the two methods with the same action name? According to the [built-in-routing-conventions](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/03-02-built-in-routing-conventions/): A request to `/odata/Events/` should be dispatched to `Get()` action. IMO, this is a behavior by design. If you want to filter by date, why not use `$filter` ?

Comment: the request is coming from a syncfusion control and I can't control how the request is generated beyond providing the destination url. If I could provide $filer I would.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to an issue with routing:

https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/1794

wish the search gods had pushed this link to the surface yesterday. 3rd result on my search today.